# How do I split a large Dataset in 2 for validation with Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

I'm using [Tensorflow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/) in Node.js with an Nvidia CUDA-capable GPU (note that this is NOT Python), and I have implemented an AI model. I have a `Dataset` object that represents the input data I would like to train my model on.

However, I would like to do an 80% - 20% split on my data, with 80% used for training, and 20% used for validation.

In the [`.fitDataset()` method](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.7.0/#tf.Sequential.fitDataset), the `validationData` setting is present for  specifying validation data.

Unfortunately though, I have just a single Dataset object that represents my entire dataset.

Additionally, my training data is both temporal and extremely large - and my `Dataset` object is backed by a Generator function. To this end, I'd like the last 20% of the the `Dataset` object to act as my validation data.

**What's the most efficient way to split a single `Dataset` object in 2 without loading it all into memory such that I can use the last 20% of it as validation data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not all loaded in memory but iteratively. So a filtering can be applied on the loaded data to split into two datasets

```
// first load the dataset
const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(csvUrl);

//split dataset
let i = 0;
trainDataset = csvDataset.filter(x => i++%5 !== 0)
i = 0
testDataset = csvDataset.filter(x => i++%5 === 0)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't quite understand the `i` variable there though. Where is it being incremented?
Anyway, if I wanted only the last contiguous 20% and I knew how many entries I have, I could filter on `i >= total * 0.8`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to increment `i`. If you want the last 20% and you know how many rows you initially have, you can use the `skip` operator. If you want the first rows, you can use the `take` operator